# Suggestion for marketplace db schema

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema

I am going to start work on a marketplace for home related needs, I need your suggestion to build better and efficient db schema.

Currently I am planning...

```
tbl_managers (id, username, password, email, created_at)
tbl_states(id, state)
tbl_cities(id, state_id)
tbl_profile(id, created_at, manager_id, city_id)
tbl_painters (id, name, address, profile_id, created_at) 
tbl_mechanics(id, name, address, profile_id, created_at)
tbl_reviews(id, profile_id, comment)
```

Is above approach correct or I should do like following...

```
tbl_managers (id, username, password, email, created_at)
tbl_states(id, state)
tbl_cities(id, state_id)
tbl_painters (id, name, address, manager_id, city_id, created_at) 
tbl_mechanics(id, name, address, manager_id, city_id, created_at)
tbl_painters_reviews(id, painter_id, comment)
tbl_mechanics_reviews(id, mechanic_id, comment)
```

Please suggest best approach.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's not that easy to get you an appropriate answer to your question.
Do you have experience in database design? You should take a look at relational databases and normalizing your database. You should mind map you idea and create a database-schema on top of it. After this step you should go thru the first 3 steps of normalizing the database. This contains splitting your tables to avoid anomalies.

It is always recommended to study existing database schemas before trying to create a improved one. Make sure that you know what you like to improve before you create a new one from scratch (you might spend way to much time by "inventing everything by yourself")

If you have concrete questions to your table layout - feel free to ask them here on stackoverflow.

Best Regards
K

Comment: yes i have basic structure of db but as this project is bigger and would require a lot of tables, so i have decided to take a suggestion.

Comment: we don't know the functional background of your marketplace. You should be able to put you mechanics and painters into one table (example: tbl_worker) with a specific flag/column which is referencing to another table which contains all type of worker. This should be the routine for further designing. With this in mind you are able to extend your database with more types of worker without manipulating the database-model.